# How to delete a postgresql unique constraint using prisma?

Tags: postgresql, prisma, pgadmin

I am using PostgreSQL as the database. Innitially I introspected my existing database by using this query `npx prisma db pull`. Then baseline the generated file to the database.

I noticed that after generating the Prisma data model there are no unique constraints (although my db has a lot of unique constraints), instead it has generated unique indexes. But as the functionality of index and constraint is almost the same so I ignored it.

It was working well until I tried to delete one of the unique indexes. The problem arises here. It says I `cannot delete index "x" because constraint "x" requires it. HINT: You can drop constraint "x" on table "table_x" instead.`

So I tried to update the generated sql migration file to delete the constraint "x". Now, another error is that `ERROR: constraint "x" of relation "table_x" does not exist`. But it's still there in the Postgres data. Even I can view the constraint "x" using pgadmin.

But the constraint was missing from the generated Prisma model. I must need to delete the constraint. So what could be the solution in this case? How can I delete the unique constraint?

**Note that:** I was also able to delete the unique constraint from the pgadmin but after doing this the prisma shows an error that my database is not synced with prisma migration history.